# ProgressDIalog freezing during load data from Retrofit + RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I am using a `ProgressDialog` to be presented before making a Rest request using [Retrofit + RxJava](http://randomdotnext.com/retrofit-rxjava/), the response of the request is large and this is freezing the animation of `ProgressDialog`. How can I fix this? I only found examples saying to use `runOnUiThread` or the `doInBackground` with `AsyncTask` but, I'm using `RxJava`. I tried the `runOnUiThread` but it did not work.

```
//My request
public void getMyData(final MyListener listener) {
AppApi AppApi = getInstanceMyApi();

        AppApi.getMyData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<ResponseData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                       //error
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ResponseData response) {
                        //success, send data to presenter to update view
                    }
                });

//Presenter call ws
public void attemptGetDataFromWS() {
    showProgress();
    getMyData(this);
}

@Override
public void onGetMyDataSuccess(ResponseData response) {
     hideProgress();
}

@Override
public void onGetMyDataError(String error) {
     hideProgress();
}
```

Comment: You should provide some code.

Comment: you should show your code

Comment: I update with some code.

Comment: it's maybe the parsing progress freezes your app. You should show more code (parsing or doing anything in UI thread)

Comment: yep show what you are doing when onNext gets called

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getMyData(final MyListener listener) {
AppApi AppApi = getInstanceMyApi();

        AppApi.getMyData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<ResponseData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                         dispose();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                       listener.onGetMyDataError(e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ResponseData response) {
                        listener.onGetMyDataSuccess(response);
                    }
                });

//Presenter call ws
public void attemptGetDataFromWS() {
    showProgress();
    getMyData(this);
}

@Override
public void onGetMyDataSuccess(ResponseData response) {
     hideProgress();
}

@Override
public void onGetMyDataError(String error) {
     hideProgress();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow this method .this is calling example with REST API + Retrofit

```
private void callRestAPI() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASEURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    newsAPI = retrofit.create(NewsAPI.class);

    Call<JSONResponse> call = newsAPI.topNews("soure", "api-key");

    // Set up progress before call
    final ProgressDialog progressDoalog;
    progressDoalog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDoalog.setMax(100);
    progressDoalog.setMessage("Its loading....");
    progressDoalog.setTitle("ProgressDialog bar example");
    progressDoalog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    // show it
    progressDoalog.show();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
            // close it after response
            progressDoalog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override public void onFailure (Call < JSONResponse > call, Throwable t){
        // close it after response
        progressDoalog.dismiss();
    }
});
}
```